# I want to use conditonal based object under object in sendinf API request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

here I want to add some condition where like the `process.env.environment==='production'` only add few more headers value

```
const api_resp = await axios({
            url,
            method,
            baseURL: `${facebookURL}/data-management/client/`,
            transformResponse: [function (data) {

                return data;

            }],
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': `application/data-management-120+json`,
                Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`,
            },
            data: payload,
        });
```

Now if the env is production as like stated above, It should add

`'CLIENT-ID': 'xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx',
 'CLIENT-SECRET': 'XXXX_XX_XXX_XXXX_XXX',`

these values in headers, only if `process.env.environment==='production'` or else it won't add those above two lines in header.

```
const api_resp = await axios({
                url,
                method,
                baseURL: `${facebookURL}/data-management/client/`,
                transformResponse: [function (data) {

                    return data;

                }],
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': `application/data-management-120+json`,
                     Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`,
                    'CLIENT-ID': 'xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx',
                    'CLIENT-SECRET': 'XXXX_XX_XXX_XXXX_XXX',

                },
                data: payload,
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const headers = {
  'Content-Type': `application/vnd.assaabloy.ma.credential-management-120+json`,
  Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`,
}

if (process.env.environment === 'production') {
  headers['CLIENT-ID'] = 'xxx';
  headers['CLIENT-SECRET'] = 'xxx';
}

const api_resp = await axios({
  url,
  method,
  baseURL: `${facebookURL}/data-management/client/`,
  transformResponse: [function (data) {
    return data;
  }],
  headers,
  data: payload,
});
```